# Migrar archivo CSV a HBASE

Tags: base-de-datos, csv, nosql

Estoy aprendiendo a usar hadoop y hbase y se me presento esta problematica que me tiene algo enredado entre todas estas tecnologias.

Tengo sobre fedora 24 hadoop y hbase funcionando. y tengo unas bases de datos en archivo CSV. quiero cargar estos archivos al formato NOSQL de hbase. existe la foma de resolver esto sin pasar por map/reduce.

eh revisado documentacion relacionada al bulk loader pero aun no logro comprender la solucion.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, lo podés hacer con *Apache Pig*, que tiene un lenguaje de alto nivel llamado *PigLatin*, y es mucho más fácil que estar realizando enormes bloques de código de *MapReduce*. https://pig.apache.org/